# How properly add event using addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener, dom-events

I'm trying to add a click-event to div element, but it doesn't work.

Link to js file is under body tag so element divContainer already exists. I tried to add div-element using appendChild and add event to it in browser console and it worker.

I didn't want to add full code, but here it is. I just don't understand why addEventListener doesn't work here.

```js
         function DatePicker(id, callback) {
    let monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];

    this.render = function (date) {
        let divContainer = document.getElementById(id);
        let selectedDay = date.getDay() !== 0? date.getDay() : 7;

        let prevMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1 - selectedDay);
        let month = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
        let nextMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
        let firstDayInMonth = month.getDay() !== 0? month.getDay() : 7;
        let lastDayInMonth = nextMonth.getDay() !== 0? nextMonth.getDay() : 7;

        divContainer.innerHTML = '';
        divContainer.innerHTML +=
            '<div class="header"><div class="triangle-left" onclick="goPrev(this.parentElement)"></div>' +
            monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear() +'<div class="triangle-right" onclick="goNext(this.parentElement)"></div></div>';

        divContainer.innerHTML +=   '<div><a>Mon</a> <a>Tue</a> ' +
                                    '<a>Wed</a> <a>Thu</a> <a>Fri</a>' +
                                    '<a>Sat</a> <a>Sun</a></div><hr>';

        for(let i = 0; i < firstDayInMonth - 1; ++i)
        {
            divContainer.innerHTML += '<div class="anotherMonth"  onclick="goPrev(this)">'+(prevMonth.getDate() + 1 + i)+'</div>';
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < nextMonth.getDate(); ++i)
        {
            if((i+1) === date.getDate()) {
                let div = document.createElement('div');
                div.classList.add('selectedDate');
                div.innerText = 1+i;
                divContainer.appendChild(div);
                div.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hello World!");});
            }
            else {
                let div = document.createElement('div');
                div.classList.add('currentMonth');
                div.innerText = 1+i;
                divContainer.appendChild(div);
                div.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });
            }
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < 7 - lastDayInMonth; ++i)
        {
            divContainer.innerHTML += '<div class=\"anotherMonth\"  onclick="goNext(this)">'+(1 + i)+'</div>';
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: try `document.getElementById('existing_id')`

Comment: Where is `id` declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you pass a valid `id` into `.getElementById()` and that element has already been parsed into the DOM, the code will work:

```js
// You must pass a string with a valid id
let divContainer = document.getElementById("container"); 
for(let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('selectedDate');
  div.textContent = 1+i;  // Use textContent. innerText is non-standard
  div.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });
  divContainer.appendChild(div);  // Append last for better performance in many cases
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code, when referencing an existing element, works just fine:

```js
let divContainer = document.getElementById('existing');
for(let i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('selectedDate');
  div.innerText = 1+i;
  divContainer.appendChild(div);
  div.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });
}
```

```html
<div id="existing"></div>
```

But it is best to only use`click` handlers on `<button>`, `<a>` and `<input>` elements to improve the ability of a screen reader working correctly with your site.